# what should I put as my 'Group' in gunicorn service file

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, gunicorn

I'm runnng an EC2 on ubuntu 18.04 , but I'm not sure if I've set the 'Group' correctly in the gunicorn service file, currently I have 'www-data'.  When I list the groups by entering command 'groups' it shows the list of users, but I can't see 'www-data', am I doing this correctly?:

groups:

```
ubuntu adm dialout cdrom floppy sudo audio dip video plugdev netdev lxd
```

current gunicorn service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=ubuntu
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/djangoapp1
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/env/bin/gunicorn \
--access-logfile - \
--workers 3 \
--bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
djangoapp1.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my gunicorn service file was correct but I didn't have www-data in my groups, now I'm able to write to my file directory, I added 'www-data' group by:

```
sudo adduser www-data <user>
```

you can check it was added by entering:

```
groups <user>
```

then I also had to change my file user permissions to 'ubuntu' user, this allows me to write to the directory,  I did this by entering:

```
sudo chown <user>:<user> -R <path to directory>
```